# Facebook Graph API : How to get someone info

Tags: facebook

I have a website with "Login With Facebook" function.
Now it worked well.

I store fb_id of each user that login to my website.
I want to know . How can I query/get their information while offline in my website.

just like:

```
$testData=$facebook->api("/?ids=12345678/likes");
```

I know that the new API will be upgraded in April 2015 and some functions will be unable to use.

Comment: Which language are you using?  From the text given I'll assume you are using jQuery?

Comment: You need to store the access token for the user. Just storing the id of the user will not let you do anything